# How to set mysql user variable when report loading Birt

Tags: mysql, variables, birt

Im using birt reporting tool since from year. its cool product very good.

Today i got a problem. that i want to set mysql user varible when report loading as a example `SET @user="USR009";`

I tried several ways to do this i couldnot get the answer could some one help me on this issue very thank full

im stuck on this problem

regards
roshan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Was resolved create a SP

```
delimiter //
 Create  PROCEDURE abcd(param INT)
     BEGIN
       SET @USER=param;
       SELECT @USER;

END//
```

And in your query call the SP with varible;

works like charm

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value in the query using a report parameter, and initialize it in the script.

1. Add a report parameter (PARAMETER_1)
2. Add "SET @user = QUERY_PARAMETER;" before your select statement in your data set.
3. While the data set is selected, select the script tab and find the "beforeOpen" drop-down.  In here, add a line: `this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("QUERY_PARAMETER", params["PARAMETER_1"].value);`

The script will replace all instances of QUERY_PARAMETER with the text.  You might still need quotes around it in the set statement (i.e SET @user = "QUERY_PARAMETER";).

[image: Parameter List]

[image: Edit Data List]

[image: Script]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I tried this way but error is coming called 


The following items have errors:

Table (id = 142):
- Cannot get the result set metadata.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
SQL error #1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from vw_hs_hr_ello' at line 3
 ;

Comment: The error means the SQL isn't valid.  You may have to put quotes around the QUERY_USER, so it reads SET @USER="QUERY_USER";  Also - try the query in mysql with the QUERY_USER substituted with the text you have in your report parameter - and verify that it works there.

Comment: Scratch that - it's the query before the select that birt doesn't like.